# I want to show string type data is wrong. But it is not check multiple field together?

Tags: php

[I select a excel file. then press read button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h6BL.png)

[It need to show all string type data is strong and color red. but is is not working. it's only check first error and execute. Doesn't check another error or not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEk2Q.png)

code:

```php
<?php

echo '<h2>Parsing Excel Data</h2>';
echo '<table class="table table-hover">';

    $i = 0;
    
    foreach ($xlsx->rows() as $elt) {
     
    if ($i == 0) {
        echo "<tr><th scope='col'>" . $elt[0] . "</th><th scope='col'>" . $elt[1] . "</th><th scope='col'>" . $elt[2] . "</th><th scope='col'>" . $elt[3] . "</th><th scope='col'>" . $elt[4] . "</th><th scope='col'>" . 'Remark' . "</th></tr>";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "<tbody>";

        if(gettype($elt[0]) == 'integer' && gettype($elt[1]) == 'integer' && gettype($elt[2]) == 'integer' && gettype($elt[3]) == 'integer' && gettype($elt[4]) == 'integer'){
            echo "<tr><td>" . $elt[0] . "</td><td>" . $elt[1] . "</td><td>" . $elt[2] . "</td><td>" . $elt[3] . "</td><td>" . $elt[4] . "</td><td>" . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Candidate List</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Candidate List(Examiner)</button>' . "</td></tr>";
        }
        else{
            if(gettype($elt[0]) == 'string'){
                echo "<tr class='danger'><td style='color: red;'>" . '<h4><del>'.$elt[0].'</del></h4>' . "</td><td>" . $elt[1] . "</td><td>" . $elt[2] . "</td><td>" . $elt[3] . "</td><td>" . $elt[4] . "</td><td>" . '<h6 class="text-center">Please Input the Correct Data.</h5>' . "</td></tr>";
            }
            else if(gettype($elt[1]) == 'string'){
                echo "<tr class='danger'><td>" . $elt[0] . "</td><td style='color: red;'>" . '<h4><del>'.$elt[1].'</del></h4>' . "</td><td>" . $elt[2] . "</td><td>" . $elt[3] . "</td><td>" . $elt[4] . "</td><td>" . '<h6 class="text-center">Please Input the Correct Data.</h5>' . "</td></tr>";
            }
            else if(gettype($elt[2]) == 'string'){
                echo "<tr class='danger'><td>" . $elt[0] . "</td><td>" . $elt[1] . "</td><td style='color: red;'>" . '<h4><del>'.$elt[2].'</del></h4>' . "</td><td>" . $elt[3] . "</td><td>" . $elt[4] . "</td><td>" . '<h6 class="text-center">Please Input the Correct Data.</h5>' . "</td></tr>";
            }
            else if(gettype($elt[3]) == 'string'){
                echo "<tr class='danger'><td>" . $elt[0] . "</td><td>" . $elt[1] . "</td><td>" . $elt[2] . "</td><td style='color: red;'>" . '<h4><del>'.$elt[3].'</del></h4>' . "</td><td>" . $elt[4] . "</td><td>" . '<h6 class="text-center">Please Input the Correct Data.</h5>' . "</td></tr>";
            }
            else if(gettype($elt[4]) == 'string'){
                echo "<tr class='danger'><td>" . $elt[0] . "</td><td>" . $elt[1] . "</td><td>" . $elt[2] . "</td><td>".$elt[3]."</td><td style='color: red;'>" . '<h4><del>'.$elt[4].'</del></h4>' . "</td><td>" . '<h6 class="text-center">Please Input the Correct Data.</h5>' . "</td></tr>";
            }
            
        }

        
    }      

    $i++;
  }

  echo "</tbody></table>";

  ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it......

'''echo '

### Parsing Excel Data

';
echo '';

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($xlsx->rows() as $elt) {
 
if ($i == 0) {
    echo "<tr><th scope='col'>" . $elt[0] . "</th><th scope='col'>" . $elt[1] . "</th><th scope='col'>" . $elt[2] . "</th><th scope='col'>" . $elt[3] . "</th><th scope='col'>" . $elt[4] . "</th><th scope='col'>" . 'Remark' . "</th></tr>";
} 
else 
{
    echo "<tbody>";

    if(gettype($elt[0]) == 'integer' && gettype($elt[1]) == 'integer' && gettype($elt[2]) == 'integer' && gettype($elt[3]) == 'integer' && gettype($elt[4]) == 'integer'){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $elt[0] . "</td><td>" . $elt[1] . "</td><td>" . $elt[2] . "</td><td>" . $elt[3] . "</td><td>" . $elt[4] . "</td><td>" . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Candidate List</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Candidate List(Examiner)</button>' . "</td></tr>";
    }
    else{

        if(gettype($elt[0]) == 'string'){
            $a= "<tr class='danger'><td style='color: red;'>" . '<h4><del>'.$elt[0].'</del></h4>' . "</td>";
        }
        else{
            $a= "<tr class='danger'><td>" . $elt[0] . "</td>";
        }
        if(gettype($elt[1]) == 'string'){
            $b= "<td style='color: red;'>" . '<h4><del>'.$elt[1].'</del></h4>' . "</td>";
        }
        else{
            $b= "<td>" . $elt[1] . "</td>";
        }
        if(gettype($elt[2]) == 'string'){
            $c= "<td style='color: red;'>" . '<h4><del>'.$elt[2].'</del></h4>' . "</td>";
        }
        else{
            $c= "<td>" . $elt[2] . "</td>";
        }
        if(gettype($elt[3]) == 'string'){
            $d= "<td style='color: red;'>" . '<h4><del>'.$elt[3].'</del></h4>' . "</td>";
        }
        else{
            $d= "<td>" . $elt[3] . "</td>";
        }
        if(gettype($elt[4]) == 'string'){
            $e= "<td style='color: red;'>" . '<h4><del>'.$elt[4].'</del></h4>' . "</td><td>" . '<h6 class="text-center">Please Input the Correct Data.</h5>' . "</td></tr>";
        }
        else{
            $e= "<td>" . $elt[4] . "</td><td>" . '<h6 class="text-center">Please Input the Correct Data.</h5>' . "</td></tr>";
        }

        echo $a.$b.$c.$d.$e;
        
    }

    
}      

$i++;
```

}

echo "";'''